how can I use my tradingview indicator in python
In tradingview, I have a self-written indicator in pine script, and I would like to use it in python, without rewriting its logic in python. For example, I could connect to my account, take this indicator and apply it to the desired dataframe.
I studied several bible libraries unofficially back api and did not find the necessary functionality, maybe I missed something.

Please [edit] your question to add what you have tried so far and how it did not work for you. Additionally, Pine Script has many internal functions that do not have direct equivalents in Python.

It would be worth mentionning what exactly and why you want to process your indicator in Python.
If you want to iterate over your indicator logic from an external service or environement, you can do so using alerts and webhooks.
There is an option in trading view to send alerts to the endpoint of your choice (webhook), it won't exactly allow you to apply your pine script indicator to a DataFrame, but you could iterate in Python over your pine script strategy through alerts signals and pass some data in the message body ...
This Pine Script option is called webhook and is officially described here:
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000529348-about-webhooks/
